# Google Invisible Recaptch Integration in PHP

Tags: recaptcha

1. Login with your google account

2.Visit the google recaptcha link.

3.Then follow the link to code integration, follow the code for both client and serverside validation. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

4.Increase or decrease the security level once after creating the recaptcha, go to the advance settings here, https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list

```
    <!--
i.stack.imgur.com slash NqyVT.png
6aZNw.png
n5gfN.png

Button     HTML
    <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="put the key here"
      data-callback="onSubmit"
      data-size="invisible"
      data-callback="callback"></div>
    <button id='btnsubmit' class="c-button--primary">Submit</button>
//Apply the exact script from document 

    //PHP Validation 
    if($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] != ''){
            $post_data = http_build_query(['secret'=>'put the secret key here', 'response'=>$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ]);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     
            // Send the request
            $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
            // Free up the resources $curl is using
            curl_close($ch);
            //print_r($result);exit();
            $hostname = strtolower($result['hostname']);
            //echo $hostname.' - '.$result['success'];exit();
            if($result['success'] == 1 && ($hostname == 'www.yousiteurl.com')){
                //Write here actual execution code for email or data submit
            }
    }
    -->
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
    alert('thanks ' + document.getElementById('field').value);
  }

  function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!document.getElementById('field').value) {
      alert("You must add text to the required field");
    } else {
      grecaptcha.execute();
    }
  }

  function onload() {
    var element = document.getElementById('submit');
    element.onclick = validate;
  }
</script>
Before body tag close
<script>onload();</script>
```